# prove $ \sum_{i=1}^{n}= I(p_i) \ge n \log n$ self entropy

Tags: information-theory, entropy, jensen-inequality

> If ${p_1,p_2,...p_n}$ is a probability distribution and $I(p_i)$ is self information entropy for each probability $p_i$, prove that
>   $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}I(p_i) \ge n \log n.$$

I can use Jensen inequality 
since this is a concave up function so  
for $ f(X) = n \log n$ 
and I know that  $I(p)=-\ln (p)$ 
$-\sum_{i=1}^{N}\log_2 p_i \geq n \log n$ 
$\sum_{i=1}^{N}p_i\log_2 \frac{1}{p_i} \le  \log \sum \frac{1}{p}p$ 
this same as entropy(?) 
$\sum_{i=1}^{N}p_i\log_2 \frac{1}{p_i} \le  \log \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{1}{p}p$  
$\sum_{i=1}^{N}p_i\log_2 \frac{1}{p_i} \le  \log n$

I'm not sure how can I get the $n \log n$?

Comment: $\sum^n_{i=1}=I(p_i)$ doesn't make sense! What do you mean? The sum of what gives $I(p_i)$?

Comment: sorry i edit the right inequality @Naji

Answer (score 2):

If you have $f(x)=\log x$, which is concave down, you have $$f\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n p_i}{n}\right)\geq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n f(p_i)}{n}$$ or $$-\log n\geq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} -I(p_i)}{n}$$which is the same as $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} I(p_i)\geq n\log n$$

Comment: thankyou so much but $f\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n p_i}{n}\right)$ by jensen inequality you apply function to $E(x)$right? why you divide by n inside the function

Comment: I applied Jensen's inequality to $p_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$.

Comment: but why you divide it with n? 
$f(E[X]) \geq E[f(x)]$ so
$f(\sum_{i=1}^n 1.p_1+2.p_2+..n.p_n)\geq\sum_{i=1}^n 1.ln(p_i)+..n.log(p_i)$  is this right? ,here is $x=p_i$?

Comment: Jensen's inequality says that if $f$ is concave down, then $f(\frac{a_ix_i}{a_i})\geq \frac{\sum a_i f(x_i)}{\sum a_i}$. I put $f(x) = \log x, x_i = p_i, a_i = 1$.

Comment: @Episksalad i just want to make sure , weights are a=1/n ? then sum in denominator will be 1?  and in

Answer (score 1):

You are defining $I(p_i) = -\ln p_i$ and thus seek to prove that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n -\ln p_i \ge n \ln n.
$$

Note that $\sum_{k=1}^n p_k = 1$ therefore by AM-GM,
$$
\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^n p_k} \le \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n p_i = \frac{1}{n},
$$
so it follows that
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{p_k} \ge n^n,
$$
and taking natural logarithms of both sides should finish the job.

Comment: thanks but how do you know you can use  AM-GM  tor prove this?

Comment: @fiksx it's a standard result, with many classical proofs, for example using Jensen's inequality. Look, e.g., [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

Comment: here $x=p_i$ right? but if i apply -log then the inequalities sign will change(?) and  problem like this that include summation mostly can be proved using AM=GM?

Comment: @fiksx Applying $\ln$ does not change sign, but multiplying by $-1$ does change the sign. AM-GM is my first hunch for similar results.